# Where to keep SQLite file on webhost, and encryption

Tags: database, sqlite, web-hosting

Quick question that I can't seem to find anywhere; at least not a clear cut answer.  I have an SQLite file that I upload to my webhost but if I navigate to it in a URL it can be downloaded.  How do I prevent this?  Also, I tried to encrypt the password field with md5 function but it wouldnt allow me to add an entry with it enabled. Should I use SQLite3? Any thoughts?  Thanks, I don't really like databases...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I navigate to it in a URL it can be downloaded. How do I prevent this?

You can place it above the document root.  For example, if you have a directory called `public_html` or `htdocs`, from which all of your site's files are hosted, you can simply put the database file at the same level as those directories instead of inside.

> I tried to encrypt the password field with md5 function but it wouldnt allow me to add an entry with it enabled.

MD5 is a [hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function), not [encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptography).  This means it goes one way, not two ways.

Can you explain what you mean when you say "wouldn't allow me to add an entry"?

> Should I use SQLite3?

If you have it available, you should.  There has been talk of deprecating the old 2.x-based SQLite functionality.

Comment: Every time I use SQLiteManager to insert a field with md5 it doesnt allow it...It also wont let me delete rows from a table, but oh well

Comment: I dont think I'll use it now that it doesnt encrypt

Comment: @Trevor, consider using a different tool, like the SQLite command line or [one of their other recommended admin tools](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ManagementTools).  SQLite *doesn't care* about the type of data, so **nothing** is preventing you from using properly salted hashes to store passwords.  Stick the result in a plain old regular `TEXT` field and call it good.

Answer (score 0):

If you upload your db, don't upload it directly to a folder within your htdocs/documentroot folder. You may restrict access to it, for example if you're using apache, you can set it in the .htaccess file.

Create a separate folder on the same level as the documentroot:

```
/htdocs
/database     <-- upload your db to this folder
...
```

So nobody can access it with a URL.

Comment: I can still access that with a url when it is in a new directory

Comment: I just changed the file permissions to a 0600 and that worked